# Unable to connect to mysql database running on a Virtualbox ubuntu VM with host-only network

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, spring-boot, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox running on my Mac, with a host-only networks adapter with an IP address of `192.168.56.15`. I have set the ip address of the VM to `192.168.56.107`.

```
Host : MacOs High Sierra
Guest VM: Ubuntu
```

I have installed and configured a mysql database on the VM and I have set the user `appuser` to have remote access to the database.

Now, on my Mac i have a sprintboot application running within eclipse, when I try to run the springboot application. I get the following error.

```
2017-09-29 14:43:02.545  INFO 3886 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-29 14:43:02.545  INFO 3886 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Fri Sep 29 14:43:12 BST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-09-29 14:43:12.835 ERROR 3886 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'192.168.56.15' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
```

**Why do I get this error?** I have specified all the correct values. Here is my application.properties file. **Note that the IP in the error is the IP of host-only adapter in VirtualBox.**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.107:3306/appdatabase
spring.datasource.data-username=appuser
spring.datasource.data-password=******
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**How do I fix this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection to MySQL is working fine since you're not getting any connection exception. However, your authentication fails since you're trying to log in with an empty username as seen in the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'192.168.56.15' (using password: NO)
```

You're using properties called `spring.datasource.data-username` and `spring.datasource.data-password`. These properties are not known to Spring boot. The correct properties are `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password`:

```
spring.datasource.username=appuser
spring.datasource.password=******
```

A list of common properties can be found in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: Darn, that was very silly of me, and I thought there was something to do with host only networks. I am still wondering why it is taking the host only network adaptor IP address.